# How to fill 3D array with zeros?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, c++11, multidimensional-array

I am trying to fill a 3d array with zeros to "reset" all elements in the array with `std::fill`.

With a 2d array it works fine to use `std::fill` function like this:

```
float histogram2D[28][28] = {{0}};
//give the array some values here then trying to reset it with zeros.....
fill( &histogram2D[0][0], &histogram2D[0][0] + sizeof(histogram2D), 0 );
```

Trying to fill a 3d array with zeros with the `std::fill` function does not work and I get the error: *segmentation fault*(core dumped)

```
float histogram3D[28][28][28] = {{{0}}};
//give the array some values here then trying to reset it with zeros.....
fill( &histogram3D[0][0][0], &histogram3D[0][0][0] + sizeof(histogram3D), 0 );
```

Does anybody know how to use `std::fill` function if its even possible with a 3d array?

Comment: The c++ version that i have does not support the initializing of a array like that. But that is not my problem. When giving my histogram3D values i want to "reset" it to zeros afterwards with the std::fill function and it is not working.

Comment: Your pointer arithmetic is wrong. The second parameter should be `&histogram3D[0][0][0] + sizeof(histogram3D) / sizeof(histogram3D[0][0][0])`.

Comment: @rpress ohhh, of course thnx. Appreciate your help :).

Answer (score 6):

> I get the error: `segmentation fault`(core dumped)

The `sizeof(histogram3D)` returns value equalent to [`28 * 28 * 28 * sizeof(float)` that is `87808`](https://godbolt.org/z/j9dsfo).
When you do `histogram3D[0][0][0]`, you are accessing the single `float` array element in the 3D array. Therefore in this line

```
fill( &histogram3D[0][0][0], &histogram3D[0][0][0] + sizeof(histogram3D), 0 );
```

you have access out of bounds [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub#Access_out_of_bounds) since you are trying to access the element which is not there. The UB means anything could happen. In your case, you just got a segmentation fault.

---

> Does anybody know how to use `std::fill` function if it's even
> possible with a *3d array*?

**Yes, Indeed** it is possible because a  *3d array* is still allocated as a contiguous block of memory where it packs its elements.

It will be then

```
#include <algorithm> // std::fill

std::fill(
   &arr3D[0][0][0],
   &arr3D[0][0][0] + sizeof(arr3D) / sizeof(arr3D[0][0][0]),
   0.f);
```

---

However, I would prefer [`std::fill_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n), as it just required the starting iterator (i.e. a pointer to the first element) and the size of the array.

```
#include <algorithm> // std::fill_n

std::fill_n(&arr3D[0][0][0], 28 * 28 * 28, 0.f);
```

Now to generalize this for any 3d-array with any initializing value, we can provide [a templated function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template) as follows:

```
#include <algorithm> // std::fill_n, std::fill
#include <cstddef>   // std::size_t

template<typename Type, std::size_t M, std::size_t N, std::size_t O>
constexpr void fill_3D_array(Type(&arr3D)[M][N][O], const Type val = Type{}) noexcept
{
   std::fill_n(&arr3D[0][0][0], M * N * O, val);
   // or using std::fill
   // std::fill(&arr3D[0][0][0], &arr3D[0][0][0] + (M * N * O), val);
}
```

### **([See Live Demo Online](https://godbolt.org/z/x7c7Ka))**

Comment: Bjarne Stroustrup would accept this answer. He writes in his book: Don't use raw arrays, you will have problems. Use vector instead, it was built to support many things that raw arrays cannot do or are doing in a dangerous way.

Comment: but these are not really 3D arrays and data will not be contiguous and won't be cache-friendly

Comment: @phuclv Yes of course, it is bad. I just wanted to point out that, about the convenience of having `std::vector`. Anyways, I have updated the array approach.

Answer (score 0):

use memset function as memset(histogram3D, 0, sizeof(histogram3D));